# ELMAH user not saving

Tags: asp.net, sql, winforms, error-handling, elmah

I'm using ELMAH to log errors within my webforms vb.net website.  The errors are saving within ELMAH_ERROR table in my SQL Database.  I'm using Forms authentication.  However when a user is logged into my system and they receive an error which then inserts into the ELMAH_ERROR table, the name of the user is not inserting.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Is anything being inserted in the user field such as the user id or is it empty/null?

Comment: The column is empty - nothing is showing.

Comment: Thx. 2 more questions: 1) when you call User.Identity.Name in your code behind, what do you see (you should see the user name)? 2) What is the type of error that occurs (some errors - like role provider errors - happen before the user profile is available)?

Comment: Could you please update your question to show how you implemented this? From what I know, when I implemented this it was very straight forward, my guess is something is wrong on the implementation.

Comment: My User.Identity.Name was blank - my system is entirely designed around customized roles.  So I authenticated the username - and it is now inserting into the database column.  Thanks for your help Michael :)